# VS Code disable certain extensions for a specific subdirectory of a workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was wondering whether it is possible to disable extensions for a certain path within the workspace?

Some extensions just crush my laptops performance when opening big files 3000+lines. (Higlighting etc..)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No, VS Code does not provide a generic solution to disable extensions within specific paths, but extensions can certainly offer this functionality on their own. Please report the performance issues to the offending extensions and consider filing a feature request to enable/disable the extension for a specific path.

You can also **disable extensions within individual workspaces**. Just open the extension's page, click the `disable` button, and select `workspace`

[image]

This will disable the extension within the current workspace only.

Here's more info on managing extensions: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_manage-extensions

Comment: So how to disable certain extensions from the command line?

Comment: How can you do this through JSON settings?

Answer (score 10):

If what you have to do is open the project and then in the extensions section, look for the extension you want to disable, and then look for disable(workspace), the workspace tells you that the extension will be disabled only for that current project.

[image]

Comment: this is not what the question is asking about.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, As of 2021 you can change the extensions settings for specific Workspace in VS Code.
The flow is as follows

- File > Preferences > Settings.
- You are going to see two different tabs labelled
  User and Workspace.
  --> Select Workspace > Extensions > Turn on or off extensions you desire.

Comment: I see the list of extensions for the workspace, but I don't see a way to easily disable an extension. I can scroll down through the preferences for each extension, but most don't seem to have a simple "disable" checkbox. What am I missing?

Comment: Most of them have sub checkboxes for more specified options. You should search for the feature you're trying to enable/disable.

Comment: this is not what the question is asking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can't *disable* an extension for a subfolder of a workspace.

You can completely exclude a file from VS Code's knowledge and extensions that use VS Code's filesystem API instead of manually using NodeJS's filesystem API by using the `files.exclude` setting.

If you want only a specific extension to not "see" a specific file, or subdirectory, etc. you'll need to see if your extension provides a mechanism to do that, such as a setting. For example,

- The C/C++ extension has `C_Cpp.files.exclude`, `C_Cpp.exclusionPolicy`, and `C_Cpp.codeAnalysis.exclude`.
- The builtin NPM extension has the `npm.exclude` setting.
- For Prettier, you can use a .prettierignore file (see also the `prettier.ignorePath` setting).
- For ESLint, use a ignore file (see also the `eslint.onIgnoredFiles` and `eslint.ignoreUntitled` settings).

If your extension doesn't have such a setting, you can politely ask your extension's maintainer to add such a feature on their issue tracker. Make sure to check if such an issue ticket has been raised already.

See also the `files.watcherExclude` and `search.exclude`.

Answer (score -1):

[image: VS Code Extension Snippet]

You can manage extensions from the three dot (...) icon and for individual extensions use the gear icon and disable them one by one.